# How to create new element from the element that has the difference from its attribute value and first letter value of its child element in XML?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing my research for bachelor degree making XSLT 1.0 with Cooktop 2.5 to transform XML files to another. Now, I get stuck on transforming this form of XML. I have XML like this:

```
<PlantModel>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="113">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-113"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LG-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIT-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LV-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIC-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
</PlantModel>
```

and I want to transform it to be like this :

```
<PlantModel>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="P-113">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-113"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="T-113">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-113"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-113"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="L-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LG-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIT-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LV-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIC-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="T-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="P-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-107"/>
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
</PlantModel>
```

I have tried XSLT from the first answer and modify it like this :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="key" match="/PlantModel/InstrumentLoop/Association" use="substring(@TagName,1,1)" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<Plantmodel>
<xsl:for-each select="/PlantModel/InstrumentLoop/@TagName">
<xsl:variable name="attrVal" select="." />
<xsl:for-each select="/PlantModel/InstrumentLoop/Association[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key',substring(@TagName,1,1))[1])]">
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <xsl:attribute name="TagName">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'-',$attrVal)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('key',substring(@TagName,1,1))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="." />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </InstrumentLoop>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:for-each>
</Plantmodel>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this is make the Association element output repeating like this :

```
<PlantModel>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="P-113">
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="T-113">
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="L-107">
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LG-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIT-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LV-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIC-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="T-107">
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
  <InstrumentLoop TagName="P-107">
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-113"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-107"/>
     <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-107"/>
  </InstrumentLoop>
</PlantModel>
```

Comment: Please post you transformation attempt.

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru I have tried XSLT with xsl:for-each and xsl:choose but I fail. Now I have tried another xsl from the answer but I still have the problem.

Comment: I have updated the solution based on the newer input provided by you i.e. multiple `<InstrumentLoop>` nodes having different `@TagName` values. If you can edit the question and update the sample input XML, my answer should help.

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for wrong sample that I gave yesterday. Thank you so much @AniketV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be achieved using `grouping` of `XSLT`. Below is the updated solution for the newer sample input XML. The output can be achieved by creating a `key` which is a combination of first character of `Association/@TagName` and the string after the `hyphen` separated by the delimited `|` symbol which hopefully would not appear the input XML.

```
<xsl:key name="key" match="Association" use="concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'|',substring-after(@TagName,'-'))" />
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="key" match="Association" use="concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'|',substring-after(@TagName,'-'))" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Association[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key',concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'|',substring-after(@TagName,'-')))[1])]">
            <InstrumentLoop>
                <xsl:attribute name="TagName">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'-',substring-after(@TagName,'-'))" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('key',concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'|',substring-after(@TagName,'-')))">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </InstrumentLoop>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT when applied on the modified sample input XML viz. multiple `<InstrumentLoop>` nodes should provide the desired output below.

**Output**

```
<InstrumentLoop TagName="P-113">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-113" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-113" />
</InstrumentLoop>
<InstrumentLoop TagName="T-113">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-113" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-113" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-113" />
</InstrumentLoop>
<InstrumentLoop TagName="L-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LG-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIT-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LV-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="LIC-107" />
</InstrumentLoop>
<InstrumentLoop TagName="T-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TW-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TIT-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="TI-107" />
</InstrumentLoop>
<InstrumentLoop TagName="P-107">
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PIT-107" />
    <Association Type="is a collection including" TagName="PI-107" />
</InstrumentLoop>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @aniket V. Actually I don't just have 1 InstrumentLoop element. In this XML, I have more with difference TagName attribute. That XSLT doesn't work well if there are more than one InstrumentLoop element .

Comment: The answer is based on the sample input XML that has been provided which has only one `<InstrumentLoop>` node. You need to provide correct sample XML in order to have the correct solution.

Comment: Solution updated to handle multiple `<InstrumentLoop>` nodes with different `@TagName` values. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have checked the XSLT and it worked, thank you for your kind help.